# Is the .git folder necessary in the database?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, domino-designer-eclipse

There is a .git folder inside my template database that wasn't there before AFAIK. It must have happened when I clicked Sync with On-Disk Project recently, but I really don't know exactly when or why.

It's rather annoying, because handling this folder can take quite some time when I compile the application.

Do I need this folder inside the database, and if not, how can I get rid of it, i.e. remove it from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .git folder and its content is of no use inside your database. The problem arises because the on-disk content of your database is at the same level as the .git folder. The .git folder is therefore imported into your database when you sync with the on-disk project.

You should move the on-disk content of your database to a sub folder of your Git folder.

Here's an example of the folder structure (using the [OpenNTF Domino API Demo Database](https://github.com/paulswithers/org.openntf.domino-Demo-Database)):

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... easier said than done. I found this page as well, seems I'm not the only one with this problem: https://jinoch.cz/domino-designer-and-git-folder-mystery

Comment: Is there somewhere an image (tree) for the right structure of the ODP?

Comment: Ah, right. Did that, and it seems I ruined the .git folder while removing On-Disk projects... and the names of all files no longer match with the old ones, the name of the sub-folder isn't in it. Plodding on...

Comment: At last! I created a sub-folder, recreated the ODP there, I had some issues with SourceTree but in the end it recognized the files having been moved elsewhere. What a relief. Thanks for pushing me into the right direction!!